# Shell in the C Programming language

Tags: c, shell, operating-system

I want to write a shell in the Linux operating system with the C language.

What is the name of the libraries and functions to use in this project?

thank you.

Comment: What do you want the library to do?

Comment: Please clarify, you want to write a whole shell program?, you want to invoke a shell command from a program?, you want to pipe data to a shell?

Comment: You'll want a line editor (readline / libedit), some linked and doubly linked list helpers, a parser (I highly recommend lemon) and a whole lot of patience. This question, unfortunately is just too broad as-is. If you run into a _specific_ problem, feel free to ask. Writing a shell is a _fantastic_ exercise to sharpen your skills. I wrote the shell for HelenOS, and it was the most fun I've had while programming.

Comment: i want to invoke a shell command from a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want, at the very least:

- [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html), [execv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execve.html) - for invoking a child  process.
- [waitpid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/waitpid.html) - for reaping dead child processes spawned with fork+exec.
- [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) - for installing signal handlers to:

  - Catch interruption (CTRL+C).
  - Reap dead child processes.
- [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) - for opening files when redirecting to/from files.
- [dup2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html) - for replacing STDIN/STDOUT with an opened file when implementing redirection.
- [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html) - for creating pipes.

The [Single UNIX Specification Man Pages](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) are a good resource for any additional functionality needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. You are starting a new thing, you can use whatever name you want. And the notion of Project is usually specific to some IDEs.

To code a shell, you first must know well the C programming language, and understand well several important Linux system calls (like `fork`, `execve`, `pipe`, `chdir`, `dup` etc.). So read a good textbook on these first. The system calls are available thru the standard C library, you don't need to link an extra one.

And probably, studying the source code of small shells (like [sash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell)) would help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's an interesting question and it could be a good exercise for something to know the IO mechanism of Unix. As you might know, Shell is responsible for interpreting Input , invoking the system calls and displaying the output. The program as such runs on top of the kernel. So, the exercise might give a lot of info on process execution family such as `exec*`.

Here is [one tutorial c](http://linuxgazette.net/111/ramankutty.html)overing it for you in C and this [one in Python](http://inspirated.com/2009/08/01/writing-a-minimal-shell-in-python) would help you design a quick prototype for understanding.

Comment: The shell don't pass its input to the kernel. It interprets its input and invoke system calls accordingly.

Comment: I was oversimplifying. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't some magical `emulateShell()` API call you can make for this, you are going to need to look into (in *great* depth) things like `exec`, `fork`, `popen`, `signal/sigaction` and a host of other process control things.

In addition, you'll probably need to get involved with terminal handling and so forth, things like `fcntl` and `ioctl`.

It's not really a subject that can be covered comprehensively is an answer box this size. I would suggest trying to break it down in smaller jobs so as to make your (and our) job easier.

Perhaps start with a simple program that accepts commands from the user and breaks them down into tokens for execution. That would be a good first step.

Comment: I'm not sure he needs *popen*, he needs to understand the *pipe* system call (among others). *popen* is like *system*, it uses a shell, dont provide one.